# Keras - Process single image to single Layer

Tags: keras

I want to take a single Conv2D layer in Keras and give it a single image so I can see the output activations. (I'm doing some custom layer research)

In other words, I do not want to use the fit function, nor do back prop, and no batch of images.

How is this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a `Model` instance which has the layer of your interest as an output (a bit similar to what you would do with an autoencoder to get the encoding) and you call `model.predict()` with a single image.